# Does kibana uses SSR?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elk

I am new to kibana and I want to know how does kibana generates the visualization on dashboard ?

i.e.

1. Does it uses SSR for generating Graphics/Pie charts etc. ?
2. Does it creates graphs on frontend using libraries like elastic-charts / charts.js /d3.js ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ! Kibana charts are generated on frontend using `elastic-charts`.

They were previously using D3.js for generating charts.

For more insights you can refer :

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/why-and-how-to-use-elastic-charts/298836

Comment: somewhat helpful !